# How to use custom validation in FormRequest?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have class:

```php
class CreateInvoiceRequest extends FormRequest
{
    public function messages()
    {
        return [
            'name' => 'required|string',
            'code' => 'required|string|unique: enterprise_invoces,code',
        ];
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name' => 'required|string',
            'code' => 'required|string|unique: enterprise_invoces,code',
        ];
    }
}
```

Also a custom validation class:

```php
namespace App\Rules;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Rule;

class InvoiceCode implements Rule
{
    public function passes($attribute, $value)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation error message.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function message()
    {
        return 'The invoice code sholud be in formar <number>.<number>';
    }
}
```

How to apply `InvoiceCode` rule for validator inside:

```php
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'name' => 'required|string',
        'code' => 'required|string|unique: enterprise_invoces,code',
    ];
}
```

I tried this:

```
 return [
                    'name' => 'required|string',
                    'code' => 'required|string|unique: enterprise_invoces,code',
                    'code' => new InvoiceCode()
                ];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have duplicate keys in your rules array in your last code snippet.

To define a custom rule with a built in rule you can pass in an array instead of a string like so:

```
return [
    'name' => 'required|string',
    'code' => ['required', 'string', 'unique: enterprise_invoces,code', new InvoiceCode()],
];
```

This is documented here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#custom-validation-rules

Comment: Thank you, why I pass wrong parameter name and get this common error `The given data was invalid.` instead my own?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your messages method on the FormRequest class is not correct. If you want to override the default messages the syntax should be:

```php
public function messages()
{
    return [
        'name.required' => 'The name is required.',
        'name.string' => 'The name should be a string',

        // keep adding the messages for the rules you want to override
    ];
}
```

For the rules method, it is common to use an array when you have multiple rules for an attribute to make it easier to read and if you need to include more complex logic. It should look like this

```php
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'name' => 'required|string',
        'code' => [
            'required',
            'string',
            'unique:enterprise_invoices,code', //you misspelled enterprise_invoices in your code
            new InvoiceCode
        ],
    ];
}
```

Comment: Thank you, how to set message for `new InvoiceCode`?

Comment: You did it right to include the custom message in the message method within the Rule class. Your are missing the logic in the "passes" method but I assume you are filling it in your project.